# Get literal value from repeater using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater as shown below. How to get the value of literal getting set in code behind (using the ltlText id).

Code Behind

```
 ltlTitle.Text = Core.GetString(e.Item.DataItem("Title"))
```

ASPX

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptSlideshow" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="SlideItem">
                        <div id="divBottomText" class="SlideShowBottomText">
                          <h2 ><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlTitle" EnableViewState="false" /></h2>
                          <p ><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDescription" EnableViewState="false" /></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="SlideShowBottomUnderlay">&nbsp;</div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I need `javascript` code to get to get the value of ltlTitle inside `repeater` and `div`.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var value = $(this).closest('.divBottomText').find('[id*=ltlTitle]').text();
alert(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your approach.

1. **Literal does not render any HTML tag. So you can't access Literal with javacript.** Use Label That renders as span Tag.
2. Even if you use Label, when Repeater will repeat it's items, it is likely that you will see more than one label with same name (*_lblTitle_0, *_lblTitle_1 etc). You can grab all their values in an array, select all spans that contains "lblTitle" in their IDs.
3. You have an unclosed div inside repeater. You need to close it to
   work properly.

**Here's how I would do it.**

Here's my markup, with a jquery function to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
    </title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var myArray = $("span[id*='lblTitle']").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            alert(myArray);
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptSlideshow" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="SlideItem">
                        <div id="divBottomText" class="SlideShowBottomText">
                            <h2>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' />
                            </h2>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDescription" EnableViewState="false" /></p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="SlideShowBottomUnderlay">&nbsp;</div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction();" value="TEST"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in **code behind** I have a class name MyClass, I'm creating a list of MyClass objects and setting it as datasource of the repeater in Page_Load event of my page:

```
public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptSlideshow.DataSource = new List<MyClass>()
            {
                new MyClass {Id = 1, Title = "Item 1", Description = "Item 1"},
                new MyClass {Id = 2, Title = "Item 2", Description = "Item 2"},
                new MyClass {Id = 3, Title = "Item 3", Description = "Item 3"},
                new MyClass {Id = 4, Title = "Item 4", Description = "Item 4"}

            };
            rptSlideshow.DataBind();
        }
    }

}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the test and click "TEST" button, I get this alert:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In browser open source code find = ltlTitle

You must be sure.

`id="ctl00_ltlTitle"` may be changing as.

Comment: How to get the value of ltlTitle then? Please help

Answer (score 0):

alikarakoc is right, the repeater will be mangling the ID client side, which is what all ASP.NET webforms containers do to child items. You should avoid writing Javascript that depends on the client side ID though.

One technique is to generate the Javascript using C# and inject it into the `<head>` of your page dynamically; this way you can reference the ClientID property of the Literal (or any other server control), which *will* be the correct ID (including the container name prefix).